# Timeseries data analysis in R

Tags: r, time-series, multivariate-analysis

I have a question about site, season and year differences in water quality, fish diversity and composition.

To answer these I have collected fish abundance data as well as water chemistry data from five randomly chosen sites and water chemistry from each site where fish assemblages were taken. In water chemistry I took BOD, DO, Temp, Turbidity, Current as variables. Now I have three seasons (Premonsoon, Monsoon and Postmonsoon) that were repeated for four years each from 5 sites.

I am very confused about how to analyze this type of data. I'm open to studying similar examples.

Comment: It would help if you clarified what kind of analysis you are seeking to do, and preferably present some data for people to work with.